# Objective C iOS crash: NSInvalidArgumentException -[__NSArrayI objectForKeyedSubscript:]:

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary, crash

I am getting a crash on the line that assigns id URL its value.

```
  id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[data[@"answer"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
  id url = [[json[@"widget_metadata"]valueForKey:@"value"]valueForKey:@"url"];
```

This is what the crash says

> Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
>   -[__NSArrayI objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c022cc80

I believe a way to resolve this issue is adding an if statement check like this

```
 if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
```

To make sure json is an NSDictionary. Will this resolve my crashing issue? I've purposely changed json to an array to test this out and it seems to have worked.

Comment: Please post json here, You have checked for `widget_metadata` what about `value`.? If you can post json than it will be helpful to all to check.

Comment: I don't have the JSON data, this was posted on crashlytics. This is out of the norm what the api usually gives me.

Comment: Then add check for `value` as well, This error occurs when you try to access key from `Array` or `objectforindex` from `Dictionary`

Comment: If reading JSON you really should test *all* returned objects that you want to use for correct classes, just as you do on the json object. Also note that **nil** is stored as an object of class **NSNull**.

Comment: Ask your back end to send correct json format. This is not your responsibility to handle.